# Scala - Convert List[String] to tuple List[(Int, Int)]

Tags: scala

I would like to getLine from a Source and convert it to a tuple (Int, Int). I've did it using foreach.

```
       val values = collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Int, Int)]()

        Source.fromFile(invitationFile.ref.file).getLines().filter(line => !line.isEmpty).foreach(line => {
          val value = line.split("\\s")

          values += ((value(0).toInt, (value(1).toInt)))
        })
```

What's the best way to write the same code without use foreach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map`, it builds a new list for you:

```
Source.fromFile(invitationFile.ref.file)
.getLines()
.filter(line => !line.isEmpty)
.map(line => {
  val value = line.split("\\s")
  (value(0).toInt, value(1).toInt)
})
.toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` should be a final operation, not a transformation.

In your case, you want to use the function `map`

```
val values = Source.fromFile(invitationFile.ref.file).getLines()
  .filter(line => !line.isEmpty)
  .map(line => line.split("\\s"))
  .map(line => (line(0).toInt, line(1).toInt))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for` comprehension:

```
val values = for(line <- Source.fromFile(invitationFile.ref.file).getLines(); if !line.isEmpty) {
  val splits = line.split("\\s")
  yield (split(0).toInt, split(1).toInt)
}
```

Comment: when should someone choose a `for` comprehension vs a `map` ?

Comment: `for`s are syntactic sugar.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/what-is-scalas-yield/1059501#1059501.  They'll get compiled into `map` calls (among other calls).  I find `for`s easier to read then a bunch of chained `map` calls.