# scala type mismatch error in graphX code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm new to scala, learning it for apache-spark. I wrote a simple function in scala for graphX

```
def foo(edge: EdgeTriplet[Map[Long, Double], Double]): Iterator[(VertexId, Map[Long, Double])] = {

    val m = edge.srcAttr

    for((k, v) <- m){
        if (v + edge.attr < edge.dstAttr.getOrElse(k, 10.0))
            Iterator(edge.dstId, Map(k -> v + edge.attr))

        else

            Iterator.empty

    }

}
```

Errors

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:37: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: String
                   Iterator(edge.dstId, Map(k -> v + edge.attr))
                                                          ^
<console>:35: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Iterator[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, Map[Long,Double])]
    (which expands to)  Iterator[(Long, Map[Long,Double])]
           for((k, v) <- m){
                      ^
StackTrace:
```

Why scala is treating ***v*** as string? and what is the cause of second error?

After editing the code as suggested by @Alexey, I'm getting error

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:30: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId,scala.collection.immutable.Map[Long,Double]]
    (which expands to)  scala.collection.immutable.Map[Long,scala.collection.immutable.Map[Long,Double]]
 required: Iterator[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, Map[Long,Double])]
    (which expands to)  Iterator[(Long, Map[Long,Double])]
                 (k, v) <- edge.srcAttr
                        ^
StackTrace:
```

If it helps, I'm implementing a different version of the sendMessage function from this [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/graphx/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/graphx/lib/ShortestPaths.scala)

Answer (score 1):

The first is a common problem with `+` in Scala, unfortunately. In this case you have not `k -> (v + edge.attr)`, as you probably expected, but `(k -> v) + edge.attr`. And the only `+` method on a `Tuple2` accepts `String`. To fix it, just add the correct parentheses.

The second error is because `for(...) { ... }` returns `Unit` (it's translated to a `foreach` call). You are missing [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/9204). In fact if you want to use `for`, it should be something like

```
for {
  (k, v) <- m
  x <- if (v + edge.attr < edge.dstAttr.getOrElse(k, 10.0))
      Iterator((edge.dstId, Map(k -> (v + edge.attr))))
    else
      Iterator.empty[(Long, Map[Long,Double])]
} yield x
```

I'd prefer to write it as

```
m.flatMap { case (k, v) => 
  if (v + edge.attr < edge.dstAttr.getOrElse(k, 10.0))
    Iterator((edge.dstId, Map(k -> (v + edge.attr))))
  else
    Iterator.empty[(Long, Map[Long,Double])]
}
```

Comment: First error has resolved , thanks to your solution. Still searching solution for second

Comment: please can you write the full code of the solutions to the second problem because I'm getting error mismatch found: Iterable[Any], required Iterator[(Long, Map[Long,Double])]

Comment: Edited again (hopefully this should be enough...)

Comment: I'm still getting an error but it's different. So we have made progress. I have edited the question to add error.

Comment: Look at `Map`'s scaladoc.