# How to return a yielded value from a for-loop in scala?

Tags: scala

In my project, we are migrating from Java to Scala. I have to a function in Java that uses `continue` in for loop and returns a value based on an if-condition inside the for loop as below.

```
private TSourceToken getBeforeToken(TSourceToken token) {
  TSourceTokenList tokens = token.container;
  int index = token.posinlist;     
  for ( int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    TSourceToken currentToken = tokens.get( i );
    if ( currentToken.toString( ).trim( ).length( ) == 0 ) {
      continue;
    }
    else {
      return currentToken;
    }
  }
  return token;
}
```

To convert this to Scala, I used Yield option in order to filter out the values that satisfy the else condition of the if expression as below.

```
def getBeforeToken(token: TSourceToken): TSourceToken = {
  val tokens = token.container
  val index = token.posinlist

  for { i <- index -1 to 0 by -1
        currentToken = tokens.get(i)
        if(currentToken.toString.trim.length != 0)
        } yield currentToken

}
```

I am not able to figure out how to return the value yielded from the for-loop. The error message is

```
type mismatch;
Found   : IndexedSeq[TSourceToken]
Required: TSourceToken
```

I understand that `yield` collecting all the values from the for-loop and its condition inside and is resulting in a collection: `IndexedSeq` & hence the error message. I am not able to think of a logic to form as it was written in the Java code.
Could anyone let me know how can I frame the code in Scala without using `yield` and break the for-loop once the `else` condition is satisfied ?

Comment: oh ok.. Understood now. It is a java Iterator<TSourceToken>.

Comment: why not converting it to a Scala type as well?

Answer (score 7):

There is no usual `for-loops` like in java in scala. `for-yield` is not the same as `for-loop`. It's just syntactic sugar for `flatMap`, `map` and `withFilter` functions  combinations. Also in scala is better not to use `return` keyword. The language based on *expressions* which has return value and `return` word can break the logic and another developers can't expect that.

In your case it will be better to use `find` for looking some specific element in some collection by predicate:

```
def getBeforeToken(token: TSourceToken): TSourceToken = {
  val tokens = token.container
  val index = token.posinlist

  (index - 1 to 0 by -1)
    .find(i => tokens.get(i).toString.trim.length != 0)
    .fold(token)(i => tokens.get(i))
}
```

Comment: So in this case, will `find` just break the loop for the first value, the condition is satisfied ? Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @Metadata yes, it will find first satisfied token or use default passed to `getOrElse`

Comment: I feel like this might be easier with reversing it, something like `token.container.view.take(index).reverse.find(_.toString.trim.nonEmpty).getOrElse(token)`

Answer (score 3):

a for comprehension is not the right tool for this problem: it's for mapping, not for finding.

For a straight-forward re-write that just re-writes your java code to scala, use a while loop:

```
def getBeforeToken(token: TSourceToken): TSourceToken = {
  val tokens = token.container
  var i = index - 1
  while (i >= 0) {
    val currentToken = tokens.get(i)
    if (currentToken.toString.trim.length != 0) return currentToken
    i -= 1
  }
  token
}
```

if `token.container` is some collection though, you'd probably write it without explicit iteration:

```
def getBeforeToken(token: TSoruceToken): TSourceToken =
  token.container.reverseIterator.collectFirst {
    case t if t.toString.trim.length != 0 => t
  }.getOrElse(token)
```

While in the process of migrating, it may be smart to stick with the first though, to get the almost-mechnical translation done as quick as possible, before trying to up the scala code quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can read a lot about Scala yield. Here are some nice articles:

- [HOW DOES YIELD WORK?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) By Scala docs.
- [FOR COMPREHENSIONS](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) By Scala docs.
- [Scala for/yield examples (for-loop and yield syntax)](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-for-loop-yield-examples-yield-tutorial/) By Alvin Alexander
- [What is Scala's yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1052476/2359227) By @Dario.

But I think that is the wrong way to approach this in Scala. Scala is a functional programming language, and you can use its capabalities.

Assuming `TSourceToken` is case class having two members:

```
case class TSourceToken(container: Seq[String], posinlist: Int)
```

Where you want to choose the last token that is not empty from the last posinlist ones. There are many ways to achieve that. One way I was thinking about is:

```
val tokens = TSourceToken(Seq("", "   ", "  \n   ", "real token", "\t\t", "   ", "  \n\n  ", "token to ignore"), 5)
val token = tokens.container.take(tokens.posinlist).filter(_.trim.nonEmpty).last
```

token will have `real token`, as you expect. Code run can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rOGrIO1cRzeRVaq5r4jTZA).