# How do pattern match assignments in for comprehensions translate into monadic operations?

Tags: scala, syntactic-sugar, for-comprehension, collect

I am familiar with the concept that Scala's `for` comprehensions are just syntactic sugar for monadic operations (`map`, `withFilter`, `foreach`, and `flatMap`) and the desugaring is described in [this popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/1243041).

By that logic, I was surprised to find that, when using pattern matching as part of the assignment portion of a `for` comprehension, no `MatchError` is thrown when the pattern doesn't match an element. Instead, the non-matched element is filtered out:

```scala
case class Account(id: String, role: String)
val accounts = Set(Account("a", "ADMIN"), Account("b", "USER"), Account("c", "ADMIN"), Account("d", "USER"), Account("e", "USER"))

val adminIds = for (Account(id, "ADMIN") <- accounts) yield id
// Set("a", "c") (no MatchError on Account("b", "USER")!
```

I would have expected that comprehension to translate to something like this:

```scala
val adminIds = accounts.map { case Account(id, "ADMIN") => id }

// or maybe
val adminIds = accounts.map { account =>
  val Account(id, "ADMIN") = account
  id
}
```

But of course those would throw a `MatchError`. Instead it seems more similar to this:

```scala
val adminIds = accounts.collect { case Account(id, "ADMIN") => id }
```

However, I've never seen any mention of a `for` comprehension desugaring into a `collect` call.

So how is this done under the hood?

Comment: Is not `collect` is a call to `withFilter`

Comment: Under the hood, your for-comprehension is translated to:
```val adminIds = accounts.withFilter { case Account(id: String, "ADMIN") => true; case _ => false }.map({ case Account(id: String, "ADMIN") => id })```
In other words, it's using `withFilter` due to the strictness of the collection (as mentioned in the linked answer). That results in filtering on demand.

Comment: @m_vemuri you might as well post this comment as an answer!

Comment: @CarloPrato looks like someone stole that privilege from me. But I'll go ahead and post it. I'm hopeful that I'll be rewarded for my original effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding my answer, that was originally posted as a comment.

Under the hood, your for-comprehension is translated to:

```scala
val adminIds = accounts.withFilter {
  case Account(id: String, "ADMIN") => true;
  case _ => false
}.map({
  case Account(id: String, "ADMIN") => id
})
```

In other words, it's using `withFilter`.

Summarizing from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/what-is-scalas-yield/1059501#1059501), `withFilter` was introduced in scala 2.8 and applies to strict collections (like `List`, as opposed to non-strict collections like `Stream`.) Instead of returning a new, filtered collection, it filters on-demand.

That's why you don't notice a `MatchError` when running your code.

Comment: Ah, I see. Good to know there's that default case.

Answer (score 0):

If you put that code in an IDE like Intellij and desugar you will get something like this

```
val adminIds: Set[String] = accounts.withFilter { case Account(id: String, "ADMIN") => true; case _ => false }.map({ case Account(id: String, "ADMIN") => id })
```

It's not a call to collect