# if statement inside for loop scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and I'm trying to learn it. I'm stuck with an very simple thing which I cannot figure out. I simply want, inside a for loop, to check if the current item is present in a map then use that value, otherwise calculate it with a function.
It should be preatty easy but coming from python I cannot understand where the mistake is.

```
      val predictions = for (review <- testValuesAsList;
                             if (storage.contains("review")){prediction = mymap("review")}
                               else {prediction = computeItemAvgRat(review._2, trainValuesAsList)}
                             ) yield (review._3, prediction)
      return predictions
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no `for` loops in **Scala**, [only `for` comprehensions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html); they are just [sugar syntax for `map`, `flatMap` and `withFilter` calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/what-is-scalas-yield/1059501#1059501).
And that is what is making your code fail.

IMHO, the `for` syntax is rarely better than just calling the combinators explicitly.

```scala
val predictions = testValuesAsList.map {
  case (_, b, c) => // I don't know what would be proper names for the variables.
    val prediction = myMap.getOrElse(
      key = "review",
      default = computeItemAvgRat(b, trainValuesAsList)
    )

    c -> prediction
}
```

Comment: ok got it! thanks!